# How do I use regex in C# to match Chinese characters without also matching Japanese kana?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

In C#, \p{Han} matches both Chinese characters and Japanese hiragana and katakana. I want to distinguish between them, so what do I do? Turn each char into unicode then detect whether the character is in the range?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: You should be able to exclude hiragana and katakana by their names, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks

Comment: @RufusL my solution works but I wanna know if there's another way that's not dirty like mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//For chinese chars
public bool IsChinese(string text)
{
    return text.Any(c => c >= 0x20000 && c <= 0xFA2D);
}

//For japanese chars
private static IEnumerable<char> GetCharsInRange(string text, int min, int max)
{
    return text.Where(e => e >= min && e <= max);
}
```

Usage:

```
var romaji = GetCharsInRange(searchKeyword, 0x0020, 0x007E);
var hiragana = GetCharsInRange(searchKeyword, 0x3040, 0x309F);
var katakana = GetCharsInRange(searchKeyword, 0x30A0, 0x30FF);
var kanji = GetCharsInRange(searchKeyword, 0x4E00, 0x9FBF);
```

Comment: Is `0x20000` meant to be `0x2000`? I assume it is, because `c` can't be greater than `0x20000` and also be less than `0xFA2D`.